# Getting conditionals to work within Firebase Observer

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to do a conditional within Firebase Observer.
Essentially I like to check if seat is occupied.
If it is, then orders can be retrieved.
If not then send the restaurant back to the search seat page again.
For some reason, the code within `if !taken` is never executed even if the condition is met (ie. the owner has inputted the wrong seat number). I have put it within the closure, it should run right?

```
func retrieveData (){
    var taken = false
    var seatNumber = "**an Int from other page**"
    let refCustomer = Database.database().reference().child("Restaurant").child("Customers")
        refCustomer.queryOrdered(byChild: "Seat").queryEqual(toValue: "\(seatNumber)").observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists() {
                taken = true
                let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
                self.customerFirstName = snapshotValue["Firstname"] as! String
                self.customerLastName = snapshotValue["Lastname"] as! String
                self.customerAllergy = snapshotValue["Allergy"] as! String
                self.customerID = snapshot.key
                self.allergy.text = self.customerAllergy
                self.ptname.text = "\(self.customerFirstName) \(self.customerLastName)"
            }
            if !taken {
                print ("oops")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MainPage", sender: self)
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with this code, and possibly your structure so let me see if I can point you in the right direction.

First, you can eliminate the taken varable as it's unneeded. In short

```
if snapshot.exists() {
   //handle the snapshot
} else {   //use else here as if the snapshot doesn't exist we want this code to run
   print ("oops")
}
```

Second, ensure your structure is like this

```
Customers
  cust_0
    Seat: 1
  cust_1
    Seat: 2
```

etc

Third, this is a string of "1"

```
queryEqual(toValue: "\(seatNumber)")
```

and you want to query for an Int so make it

```
queryEqual(toValue: seatNumber)
```

which queries for an Int of 1

Forth:

When querying Firebase, closures will not execute when .childAdded doesn't find anything. You should use .value.

From the docs of .childAdded

> This event is triggered once for each existing child and then again
>   every time a new child is added to the specified path.

So if no child nodes match the query, it will not execute.

Use this

```
refCustomer.queryOrdered(byChild: "Seat")
           .queryEqual(toValue: seatNumber)
           .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

And... this is the important part, .value retrieves all nodes that match the query so you will need to iterate over those nodes to work with the child nodes. Assuming there would only ever be one match then you can do this

```
guard let allChildren = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}
let firstChild = allChildren.first
```

Fifth. While technically this is ok

```
let f = snapshotValue["Firstname"] as! String
```

You are guaranteeing that a Firstname node always exists. If that's true go with it. However, a safer, more Swifty way would be to do this

```
let f = snapshotValue["Firstname"] as? String ?? "No First Name"
```